# How to get a complete vector of an image in one column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, machine-learning

How can I get a vector of an image in one column of a dataframe?
This is my code right now:

```
#making the dataframe
columnNamesIm <- c("label", "image")
dfImages = data.frame(matrix(vector(), 0, (2),
                               dimnames=list(c(), columnNamesIm)),
                        stringsAsFactors=F)

images <- list.files()
for(i in 1:length(images)){

  img <- readPNG(images[i])
  img_matrix <- img@.Data
  img_vector <- as.vector(t(img_matrix))

  #getting the label
  dataRow <- subject_ids[i]
  #putting the label and image vector together to be put in the dataframe as one row with two columns
  dataRow <- c(dataRow, img_vector)
  dfImages[i, ] <- dataRow
}
```

But when you check dfImages you will see that there's only the first value of the vector, instead of the whole vector. Like this:

[image]

But the vector actually looks like this:
[image]

How can I properly make this dataframe?

Comment: please show a sample of the desired output

Comment: As you do not provide any motivation for storing the information in a data.frame, I would suggest storing the image information in a named list instead. Something like `myList <- list(); for(i in seq_along(images)) {; ...; myList[images[i]] <- list("label"=subject_ids[i], data=img_vector)`

Comment: I want to use the dataframe to give the variables to a Neural Network algorithm. See my other post as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41100998/image-classification-with-neural-network-in-r